# Keras model.reset_states() does not work with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: tensorflow, session, keras, reset

I want to use `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession()` for training a model described in Keras. This model is a stateful model, so I want to reset the states after every epoch.

One problem is that if I call `model.reset_states()`, it generates the following error.

**RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.**

If `tf.Session()` is used instead of `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession()`, this error doesn't appear.

For example, in the following sample code even though it is not a training code, the same error message is generated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf


inputs1 = tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 10), (1, 2, 5)) 
inputs2 = tf.reshape(tf.linspace(100.0, 0.0, 10), (1, 2, 5)) 

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
    5,  
    return_sequences=True, stateful=True)
])

outputs1 = model(inputs1)
outputs2 = model(inputs2)

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() as sess:
  model.reset_states()
  print (sess.run(outputs1))
  model.reset_states()
  print (sess.run(outputs2))
```

I found two ways to resolve this problem:

1. To use `tf.get_current_graph()._unsafe_unfinalize()` before resetting the stats.
2. To use `tf.Session()` rather than `tf.train.MonitoedTrainingSession()`.

But I think both approaches are not ideal.
Could you please suggest what would the best solution in this case?